# RecordRTC isn't working perfectly

Tags: html, webrtc, recording, voice-recording, getusermedia

I would like to dive into WebRTC, particular audio recording. So I tried this [**DEMO**](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC/) and the first problem arose: when I record in the latest Google Chrome I always hear a high-pitched buzzing sound in the background which is very annoying and probably not intended.

Is that a problem with my computer / settings or is this just normal? Because if this is ordinary, WebRTC is pretty useless for my purpose.

If this is related to my audio-midi-settings – here are some screenshots:
[image: Output]
[image: Microphone Setting 1]
[image: Microphone Setting 2]

Answer (score 1):

Goto source code and comment [this line](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/blob/master/RecordRTC/RecordRTC.js#L547):

```
// __stereoAudioRecorderJavacriptNode.connect(context.destination);
```

Actually microphone is connected with speaker. This causes the recorded audio to be played back in the speakers.

**Updated:**

This workaround doesn't seems to be working. Sorry.

It was taken from [here](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/45).

Comment: No prob. I want to build a webapp which has the feature that you can record your voice. But with this whine in the background it would be no pleasure for the user…